# request to stage snapshots on oss.jfrog.org, my group Id is "com.meizu.flyme.internet"

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jcenter

I send a request  to stage snapshots on oss.jfrog.org, my group Id is `com.meizu.flyme.internet`

But I get fellow message:

> Message Detail Subject: Your request to stage snapshots on
>   oss.jfrog.org using the group ID
>   'com/meizu/flyme/internet/push-internal-publish' has been approved.

I think the right groupId approved should be `com.meizu.flyme.internet` not the `com.meizu.flyme.internet.push-internal-publish`
So I cant publish my library to oss.jfrog.org, this is error message:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':push-internal-publish:artifactoryPublish'.
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 403. HTTP response message: Forbidden

I use Artifactory gradle plugin to publish my library to oss.jfrog.org;

you can check build.gradle here :https://github.com/comsince/Gradle_Plugin_For_Publish/blob/master/plugin/build.gradle

My library groupId is `com.meizu.flyme.internet` and artifactId is `publish-plugin`

Comment: the error info:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':push-internal-publish:artifactoryPublish'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file: HTTP response code: 403. HTTP response message: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support request and not a SO question.

Comment: this is permission question about oss,after I get the answer,I will update it

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you requested too narrow path. Fixed, try now.

Comment: what is narrow path，the whole is Deploying artifact: https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/com/meizu/flyme/internet/push-internal-publish/3.3.170214-SNAPSHOT/push-internal-publish-3.3.170214-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: I try again ,but also receive the 403 error message

Comment: whether i user group "com.meizu.flyme.internet" or "com.meizu.flyme.internet.push-internel-publish"  I also get the 403 message

Comment: what user do you use in Bintray?

Comment: my username is "comsince"